# Loss function definiton for relabelling

Tags: bayesian, loss-functions, hierarchical-bayesian, definition, model-based-clustering

Taken from the appendix to the paper (Yongning Wang & Ruey S. Tsay) of this (2019) paper [Clustering Multiple Time Series with Structural Breaks](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jtsa.12434). Appendix to be downloaded her [Appendix](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/action/downloadSupplement?doi=10.1111%2Fjtsa.12434&file=jtsa12434-sup-0001-AppendixS1.pdf.)

To fix label switching, the following loss function is defined.
The most probable thing is that I misunderstand the definition of $G_{sk}$. s is indicating a given regime, $k\epsilon\{1,\cdots,K\}$ is giving the group and $n\epsilon\{1,\cdots,N\}$ is the individual. If I want to select n s.t. $n\epsilon G_{sk}$, I imagine $G_{sk}$ looks somewhat like $\left(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,...\right)^{T}$ So in case of K=3 and N=50, you get $dim(G_s)=50\times3$, but then I would need discrete optimization with $K^N$ possibilities of a $KN$, matrix, which will never get stored.

This does not seem reasonable. For context, it pertains to a loss function for label-switching. The main question remains, there is no definition of $G_{sk}$ given anywhere, and as the "action" of the loss function, the use of $n\epsilon G_{sk}$ in the summation of the loss function confuses me. I guess my question is, what do the authors mean by it.

[image]